# Fraction in siunitx

Tags: siunitx, fractions, number

Some time ago (last year) I had the following code working without errors

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
If we have \SI{2/3}{\mole} the reaction \ldots
\end{document}
```

Now I get error "invalid number '2/3' from siunitx package.
However, in my case it would be useful to keep such fraction.
Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Set `parse-numbers=false` on this quantity  or something like that, it us in the manual

Comment: This solved the problem.

Comment: In the recent siunitx [major update](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2843.1621343877.4615.ctan-ann@ctan.org) from version 2 to version 3, the `\SI` command has changed to `\qty` command. And you can still use the old commands, the author says "Where possible, older names are mapped to newer ones internally: you will be warned in the log if this is the case."